# Trying to understand how a Django foreign key works

Tags: python, sql, django, generic-foreign-key

So I'm building my first Django project now, a two-player chess website. I'm almost done and now I'm writing the tests. The project has two original models: Player and Game. The Player model has a one to one field to the User model, Player.user, and a foreign key to Game, Player.current_game, which indicates the game instance the player is currently in. The Game.draw_offered CharField takes the values "" (the default value), "w", or "b", indicating whether a draw has been offered and the color of the player who offered it. I have a test case that does the following:

```
class Draw_ViewTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.user1 = User.objects.create_user(username="Test_User_1", password="test1")
        self.user2 = User.objects.create_user(username="Test_User_2", password="test2")
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        self.game = Game.objects.create()
        self.player1 = Player.objects.create(user=self.user1, current_game=self.game, color="w")
        self.player2 = Player.objects.create(user=self.user2, current_game=self.game, color="b")

    def test_draw(self): 
        request = self.factory.get(reverse('draw'))
        request.user = self.user1
        #The draw view changes the draw_offered field of the player's current game to the player's color, and saves the current_game to the database
        response = draw(request)
        self.game.refresh_from_db()
        assert self.game.draw_offered == self.player1.color
        assert self.game == self.player2.current_game
        #self.player2.current_game.refresh_from_db()
        assert self.game.draw_offered == self.player2.current_game.draw_offered
```

All the assertions pass but the last one, but if you uncomment the second to last line, it passes.

What's going on? As I understand it, when you refer to the Foreign Key attribute self.player2.current_game, Django performs a database lookup and returns a Game instance with up-to-date fields. Since self.game and self.player2.current_game correspond to the same Game record in the database, and self.game.refresh_from_db() was just called, you would think that self.game.draw_offered == self.player2.current_game.draw_offered would evaluate to True-- both Game instances refer to the same database record and have up-to-date fields. The fact that I have to call self.player2.current_game.refresh_from_db() to make the assertion pass doesn't make sense to me-- according to my understanding of Django Foreign Keys, self.player2.current_game should automatically be up to date with the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really about foreign keys.

What you're missing is that just because two instances point to the same database record, it doesn't mean that they're the same object. Just as you have to refresh `self.game` to see the changes that were made to the underlying record in the `draw` view, you will also need to refresh `self.player2.current_game` so that it also gets those updated values.

Django won't make a database call to lookup a foreign key if it thinks it already has it: and it does, because you originally created `self.player1` and `self.player2` by passing in the entire Game object. So yes, you need to explicitly refresh the current_game object to see the changes that were made.

If you really wanted, you could probably create the objects without doing this, by passing the ID rather than the full object: `self.player2 = Player.objects.create(...current_game_id=self.game.id...)`. This way, Django won't actually have the object cached, so it will need to query it at the end of your test.

Comment: So here's my understanding. When you write x = self.player2.current_game, x's fields are automatically up to date with the database, because Django performs a database lookup whenever you refer to an object via a foreign key attribute. Your answer seems to imply that self.player2.current_game is more like a standard Python attribute reference, which points to an object stored in memory and has nothing to do with the database. Which one is correct?

Comment: No, your understanding is wrong, as I say at the start of my third paragraph. When you *initially* refer to an object's foreign key attribute, Django will go to the database to fetch it. However, it then stores it in the parent object, so subsequent references do not cause further database lookups. (Similarly, if you initially used `select_related`, Django will do a JOIN to get and cache the related object from the beginning, so no db lookups will be done.) In your case, again as I state, Django has the object from when you created it, so no need to do a db lookup.

Comment: I have a lot of views that take a request, set {player = request.user.player}, and then {game = player.current_game}, and their behavior depends on {game}'s attributes. Do I need to rewrite these views to include refresh_from_db() statements every time I do this to ensure that {game}'s attributes are up to date, or are there certain situations in which referring to a foreign key guarantees that a database lookup will be performed? Because my project seems to be working fine as it is, and I would expect there to be some problems if {game}'s attributes were outdated. Thanks for your help, btw.

Comment: No, because it is only in tests that you create an object locally, call a view which does its own fetching and processing, then assert on the values of the original local object. Everywhere else, you get objects as you need them and pass them around.

Answer (score 0):

The test runner will run `setUp`  method prior to each test, so you're operating on the instance, from before running your code. It's well explained in `Unitest` documentation.

You're not accessing fresh `player2` instance from the database, just loading it, as was defined in the `setUp` method.

Comment: Yeah, but why does that matter? Regardless of whether player2 is refreshed or not, its current_game foreign key points to the same record in the database, and calling player2.current_game should return a Game instance with the same up-to-date field values as that record. self.game corresponds to that same record, and was just refreshed from the database, so shouldn't the field values of self.game and player2.current_game be the same? Based on this behavior player.current_game acts more like a game instance whose field values are stored in memory, rather than read directly from the database.